# Strongloop: Nodejs bad content-type header

Tags: node.js, upload, strongloop

Using strongloop, I have developed an API to upload an image but there some problem and the issue that it is generating is

```
[Error: bad content-type header, unknown content-type: image/png]
```

The Method that is used for uploading i stated as follows:

```
post.remoteMethod('testing', {
    description: 'Post a message',
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'contenttype', type: 'String', description: 'eg. image/png', required: true, http: {source: 'query'}},
      {arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: {source: 'context'}}
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'success', root: true},
    http: {verb: 'POST', path: '/testing'}
});


post.testing = function (contenttype, ctx, cb) {
        console.log(contenttype , ctx);
            storageProvider.upload(ctx, function (err, response) {
                if (err) throw err;
                Log.e(err, response);
            });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave it a string content-type but its binary.  Strongloop may not support doing it that way.  See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest/issues/26

I recommend not using Strongloop because of issues like this.